# VBA Email HTML Body add Page Sperator

Tags: vba, outlook

Is there a way to add a page break / page separator in outlook email? I am currently cheating just using `"------------------------------"` but this tends to fall short on aesthetic as far as formatting goes.

Ideally I would have something similar to adding 3 dashes in Stack Overflow which adds a page break. When looking this up, I wrongly keep finding details on line breaks (`<br>`)

*below this*

---

*above this*

```
With OutMail
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "urdearboy@so.com"
        .to = Target.Offset(0, 2)
        .cc = Target.Offset(0, 3)
        .Subject = "Check Out This Email"
        .HTMLBody = "<p style = 'font-family:arial' >" _
                    & "Hi " & Target.Offset(0, 1) & ", " _
                    & "<br>" _
                    & EmailBody & "</p>" _
                    & RangetoHTML(EmailTable) _
                    & "<br>" & "<br>" _
                    & "---------------------------------------------------------------"
                    & "<p style = 'font-family:arial' >"

        'Change to .Send to actually send emails
        .Display
       Target.Offset(, -1) = "Sent" 
End With
```

Comment: I think you might be looking for an `<hr>` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using `<hr>` tag?

```
With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "urdearboy@so.com"
            .to = Target.Offset(0, 2)
            .cc = Target.Offset(0, 3)
            .Subject = "Check Out This Email"
            .HTMLBody = "<p style = 'font-family:arial' >" _
                        & "Hi " & Target.Offset(0, 1) & ", " _
                        & "<br>" _
                        & EmailBody & "</p>" _
                        & RangetoHTML(EmailTable) _
                        & "<br>" & "<br>" _
                        & "<hr>" _
                        & "<p style = 'font-family:arial' >"

            'Change to .Send to actually send emails
            .Display
           Target.Offset(, -1) = "Sent" 
    End With
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: <3 Stack Overflow. Appreciate the speedy response - I was not familiar with <hr> tag